# XSLT to Support 2 or more namespace declaration

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML that looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="myns1">
  <node1>
    <Header>
      <MessageID>1</MessageID>
      <MessageText>Message1</MessageText>
    </Header>
  </node1>
</Document>
```

or might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="myns2">
  <node1>
    <Header>
      <MessageID>2</MessageID>
      <MessageText>Message2</MessageText>
    </Header>
  </node1>
</Document>
```

And an xslt 1.0 that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:urn="myns1" exclude-result-prefixes="urn">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/urn:Document">
    <Root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="urn:node1/urn:Header" />
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match ="urn:node1/urn:Header">
    <Header>
      <ID>
        <xsl:value-of select="urn:MessageID" />
      </ID>
      <Text>
        <xsl:value-of select="urn:MessageText" />
      </Text>
    </Header>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

which outputs this

```
<Root>
  <Header>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Text>Message1</Text>
  </Header>
</Root>
```

My question is, how can i support 2 or more namespaces (e.g myns1, myns2 and myns3), is it possible, I have a big xslt file that looks exactly like the one is posted and editing the whole thing will be taking a long time, is there an easier way to do it. Because the input XML might be coming with different flavors and right now my xslt only supports one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35647813/3016153 --- P.S. There is something wrong with the situation you describe. A namespace is part of the schema. Usually, an XSLT stylesheet deals with one input and one output schema only.

Answer (score 0):

You can always have more namespaces that your XSLT uses, it is very common that the XML contains more than one namespace. I have used your example but added a namespace in both XML and XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Document xmlns="myns1" xmlns:ns2="myns2">
  <node1>
    <Header>
      <ns2:MessageID>1</ns2:MessageID>
      <ns2:MessageText>Message2</ns2:MessageText>
    </Header>
  </node1>
</Document>
```

In this XML example the MessageID and MessageTest are now in the myns2 namespace, indicated in this XML with the ns2 prefix. By tying the same namespace to a prefix in my XSLT below I can now use that in the XSLT to identify these two elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:urn="myns1"
                xmlns:urn2="myns2" exclude-result-prefixes="urn urn2">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/urn:Document">
    <Root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="urn:node1/urn:Header" />
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match ="urn:node1/urn:Header">
    <Header>
      <ID>
        <xsl:value-of select="urn2:MessageID" />
      </ID>
      <Text>
        <xsl:value-of select="urn2:MessageText" />
      </Text>
    </Header>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

EDIT:

If you want to ignore the namespaces when trying to match your xpath expression, and just use the element names you can use the local-name() function  (XSLT 1.0)

```
<xsl:value-of select="*[local-name()='MessageID']" />
```

Or if you are using XSLT 2.0 you can use:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="*:MessageID" />
```

Comment: what if lets say that the XML is constant, because we will just receive it as it is, and will always have one namespace. but I can have different XML files with a different namespace, which means one XML will have only one namespace.

Comment: I've added a solution for that as well to the answer, hope that helps.

Comment: @zyberjock, what you describe is hypothetically possible, but unlikely in practice.  A given element name in one namespace means something specific to that namespace.  In general, there is no reason at all to think that the same simple name in a different namespace means the same thing, so if you are matching on specific element names then it's unlikely that ignoring namespace differences is what you really want to do.  Do not confuse different namespaces with different namespace *prefixes* bound to the same namespace, however.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with several variants of input file structures that are similar but not identical (where variant namespaces is one possible example of this), my usual recommendation is to start by normalizing the input to one of the structures, and then writing the rest of the transformation to operate on that structure only. So in this particular case, first transform the document so it uses myns1 rather than myns2, and then you have an ordinary transformation on your hands.

The major benefits of this are that (a) it simplifies the code by separating concerns, and (b) the normalization transformation is highly reusable: you can use it whatever you intend to do with the document thereafter.